# Cookies consent popup - Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.wtwco.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: cross-domain, cypress

I am having issues with the below test scenario I am trying to automate using Cypress:

When I navigate to **http://www.willistowerswatson.com/ICT**, a pop-up for cookies is displayed. I think it's an iframe:

[image]

I want to click the "Agree and Proceed" button in order to verify text on the landing page.

Here is my current test code:

```
 it('Navigate to landing page', () => {
        cy.visit('http://www.willistowerswatson.com/ICT');
        cy.frameLoaded('[id^=pop-frame]')
 })
```

When I run this test, I get this error message in Cypress explorer:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.wtwco.com" from accessing a
> cross-origin frame.

Can someone please tell me how I can get around this to proceed with the test scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your screenshot. I only saw the [cookie banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/856H6.png) at the bottom of the page. There may be a cookie created after accepting and proceeding. You could create the cookie beforehand to bypass the the pop-up. You may also be able to click outside or hit `esc` to remove the pop-up as a workaround.